# Discord Bot-AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loop'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm a new coder, and I've been following a tutorial on how to create a discord bot with the code below having been virtually copied the code straight out from the tutorial.I have every time the same error. Any tips?

Code:

```
import discord
from discord import client

class MyClient(discord.Client) :
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("online")

async def on_message(self, message) :
    print(message.author +":"+message.content)



client =MyClient
client.run("xyz")
```

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\Matthias> & C:/Users/Matthias/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "e:/DIscord Bot/Test1.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\DIscord Bot\Test1.py", line 14, in <module>
    client.run("xyz")
  File "C:\Users\Matthias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 692, in run
    loop = self.loop
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loop'
```

Comment: You're not making an instance of it. `client = MyClient()` mind the `()` at the end. Also your events won't work because you forgot the decorators. Lastly for bots, use `commands.Bot` as it has some extra functionality. There's plenty of official examples on that in the dpy docs.

Comment: Also go to [discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/), select your bot, go to bot tab and regenerate your token. Adjust your code accordingly and take care not to post your token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `MyClient()`, not `MyClient`. (Line 12)